# Repeating an iterating function N times

Tags: python, function, for-loop, iteration

I have an iterative function, f(x) = ax + b, which I want to repeat N times. My steps are as follows
1.) Define the iterative function
2.) Assign a value to each repetition
3.) Stop at the Nth repetition

```
# Define repeating function
f += a*f + b

# Assign values to iterations 


# Stop iterating at Nth value

for i in range(N+1):
    f += f(i)
```

I'm unsure of how to label each iteration of the function. My first thought is to create a list of all values of the function.

Comment: So you want to store all the intervening values along the way to the final `N` value? Something like this is well-solved with `itertools.accumulate` typically, but it's not at all clear if that's what you're actually looking for.

Comment: `f += f(i)` This makes no sense, because you're using the name `f` as the function name and as the returned value.  Did you actually mean `i += f(i)` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "iterative function"? This concept does not exist in python. Some of the notation you use appears to be math and some is python. I recommend you break this into pieces. You need to get a clear understand of the problem you are trying to solve and use consistent notation to describe it. First write a python function `def f(x):...`. Then figure out how you can call that function multiple times. It sounds like maybe a generator would be a good tool to solve your original problem.

Comment: Hint: You can do something like `x = f(x)` in python. Coming from a mathematical background, this may be a bit confusing. The `=` here is called the assignment operator. This is NOT the same thing as `=` in math where you are defining equality. THIS IS A VERY IMPORTANT DISTINCTION TO UNDERSTAND BEFORE YOU CONTINUE. Please excuse the caps, but this is really important to emphasize. Be sure that you know what the assignment operator does, especially in this kind of context.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first thing is to declare your function, in Python there are several ways to do it. When a function is small it is usually defined as a lambda. A lambda follows the syntax.

```
func = lambda parameter1, parameter2, ..., parameter: <return value>
```

Then we would have to define the initial values, in this case I will call the final value v and the number of iterations N

The last thing is to call the function N times, for this I use a for loop

```
# Define repeating function
a = 5
b = 1
f = lambda x : a * x + b

# Assign values to iterations 
v = 0
N = 10

# Stop iterating at Nth value
for i in range(N):
    v = f(v)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**